# Windows Server 2016 Terminal Server GPO not setting Session Time Limits (as per QuickSessionCollection Properties)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-terminal-services

I have a Windows Server 2016 terminal server with a GPO applied to limit idle sessions and disconnect times.

RSOP shows `[Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Connection/Remote Desktop Session Host/Session Time Limits]` as expected.

[image: rsop]

Yet when i go to `Server Manager -> Remote Desktop Services -> Collections -> QuickSessionCollection -> Properties -> Session`

[image: properties]

Why is there this difference am I missing something in the GPO or can this only be done manually?

Do i need to use Server 2016 ADMX GPO templates?

What if i want to manage multiple servers is there no way to do this via GPO and ensure this is automated via GPO?

Comment: What does the registry say for those values? `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]`